# What is a Steiner point in poly2tri?

Tags: algorithm, polygon, triangulation

The [poly2tri Readme](https://code.google.com/p/poly2tri/wiki/README) talks about Steiner points, what are they? (Is it related to [triangle Steiner points](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steiner_point_(triangle))?)

Why would one add Steiner points?

Comment: I just want to make sure it is just for speed purpose, and that it has no effect on the type of polygon one wants to triangulate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Poly2tri has the ability to add something called Steiner Points. You can add these inside a polygon to get a triangulation with shorter edges*


Here are a few resources from what you have posted: 
1.[Triangulation of spline to mesh, questions and results](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/triangulation-of-spline-to-mesh-questions-and-results.181596/#post-1268937) (read the comments)

2.Youtube Video with concept: [Triangle Tribualtions](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FMjjVn8B7Vw)

Conceptually, i believe these are linked with the famous NP-complete [Steiner Tree Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steiner_tree_problem)

> From Wikipedia:

The Steiner tree problem is superficially similar to the minimum spanning tree problem: given a set V of points (vertices), interconnect them by a network (graph) of shortest length, where the length is the sum of the lengths of all edges. The difference between the Steiner tree problem and the minimum spanning tree problem is that, in the Steiner tree problem, extra intermediate vertices and edges may be added to the graph in order to reduce the length of the spanning tree. **These new vertices introduced to decrease the total length of connection are known as Steiner points or Steiner vertices**. It has been proved that the resulting connection is a tree, known as the Steiner tree. There may be several Steiner trees for a given set of initial vertices.


Also, you might want to look at *Euclidean Steiner Tree* on the wiki page. Seems relevant to your problem

Comment: Ok thanks! So if I understand correctly, one can add Steiner points in poly2tri to make it faster/help compute the triangulation?

Comment: I'm no expert at graphics but this seems like a valid application

Comment: Ok, so it does not affects the shape of the polygon, right? I was expecting it could help me [triangulate polygons touching themselves](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34221075/triangulate-a-polygon-whose-contour-touches-itself).

Comment: Why not try http://math.stackexchange.com/ for some conceptual help? This is beond my expertise :) Your new question seems like a legit geometry question to me

Comment: Well, actually those questions are more related to the poly2tri library, not pure geometry. But it seems I might need to reconsider the triangulation library I use...

Comment: Did you see Euclidean Steiner Trees. Maybe that's what the library is talking about?

Comment: Maybe. I could reformulate my question into "Why would you add Steiner points when using poly2tri?". I just want to make sure it is just for speed purpose and it has no effect on the type of polygon one wants to triangulate.

Comment: Maybe. If you're sure however that these are the Steiner points you wanted, you might want to consider accepting this answer :)

Comment: Yes, I'll definitely do it tomorrow if nobody gives a more precise answer! Thanks a lot for you help!

Comment: Ok, I found the answer [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/poly2tri/Yy62zJqqmYE) and [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FMjjVn8B7Vw), can you put this in the beginning of your answer so that I accept it? Something like "In poly2tri, Steiner points helps you define the way the polygon is triangulated: the final mesh will contain the given points." Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Short answer: it enables to add custom points in the resulting mesh ; like in [this video](https://youtu.be/FMjjVn8B7Vw?t=2m25s).